# how to read the request.payload contents in django?

Tags: django, http-post, httprequest

I want to make some decision based on the contents of request.payload-

```
XPKHmxbGVRRE9kUz5K6MtwL15NDedDHDb9IcTohZH7Vnrd0k5D4I0zjD4YR6yjhb
------WebKitFormBoundaryVL2R7CYuDDjkPX51
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filename"; filename="abc.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf
```

Basically want to read if filename exists in this? How can I do this?
`if "filenanme" in request.POST` seems incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check request.FILES!   It's what you're usually working with for file uploads!

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.FILES

Comment: yes. Actually there are 2 forms on the same page having a file upload- so I actually want a condition inside if request.FILES. How to distinguish? one form has parameter 'filename', other has 'file'.

Comment: thanks David- i just tries if "filename" in request.FILES and it seemed to work :)